# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[7' and how to remove the brackets

Tags: python, list, input, tuples

```
arrx=list(map(int,input().strip().split(',')))
```

I am trying the above code to get the input of `'[7,5,1,6,3,4]'` but I am getting an error of `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[7'`.

Can anyone suggest to me a way out of it?

Comment: `input().strip('[]')` Also I'd recommend you to take a look on [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.strip()` to strip them by specifying the characters:

```
arrx=list(map(int,input().strip('[] ').split(',')))
```

Note that if your input is in reality a JSON list, you can more robustly parse it as json:

```
import json
arrx = json.loads(input())
```

And if it's a Python literal expression, you can use `ast`:

```
import ast
arrx = ast.literal_eval(input())
```

Answer (score 2):

Save your breath and use [`literal_eval`](/q/29552950/5958455):

```
import ast

a = ast.literal_eval(input())
print(a, len(a), a[0], "and whatever you want")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use
[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and
[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), which search for `\d+` (1 or more digits):

```
import re
# '[7,5,1,6,3,4]'
arr = [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\d+', input())]
print(arr)
# [7, 5, 1, 6, 3, 4]
```

---

The error you were getting is due to incorrect parsing of the input: you are not removing the brackets: `[` and `]`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) `.strip()` without arguments means remove the leading and trailing whitespace. And `split(',')` splits on comma (BTW, if you have comma with whitespace in the middle of the input string, the whitespace is not removed).